# ErrorException Trying to get property 'headers' of non-object

Tags: laravel

[image: screenshot of the error]

I'm trying to create a middleware to prevent users from access to some area but I'm getting this error " ErrorException Trying to get property 'headers' of non-object ", anyone knows why?

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $current_user = auth()->user('teacher')->id;

    $checkResponsible = Teacher::select('id')->with(['ResponsibleOf' => function ($q) {
        $q -> select('name', 'responsible_id');
    }])->find($current_user);

    if(! isset($checkResponsible))
    {
        return redirect()->route('teacher.home')->with(['error'=> "You don't have permission"]);
    }
    else
    {
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing `auth()->user('teacher')->id;` instead of `Auth::id()`?

Comment: As i understood it, because i'm using multiple login system (teachers, students), to get the id of current logged user as teacher

Comment: This function is not accepting any parameters to my knwoledge, did you write another guard?
If not get the user  normally and check if he is a teacher od student seperately

Answer (score 0):

Trying to get property 'headers' of non-object

```
check your env file app url it should be same ! 

APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:MIXz8eUzPudZKcrdilaW08ueScpx5i7UJ9lxHbuVpCI=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=your app url
LOG_CHANNEL=stack
```